# Making Dll default

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll

How do l add a Dll to the default settings of visual studio?
So that when I open a new project the Dll will be added automatically like system.dll
is added by "using system;".
I'm using a lot of basic functions and I don't want to add every new project my dll

Comment: @WaiHaLee I have updated my answer. I hope now that can be the answer.

Comment: It takes creating your own project template(s).  You kick that off in VS2017 with Project > Create Template.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to create or modify one of the Visual Studio templates.

There are some [instructions on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-project-templates?view=vs-2017) about how to do this. You can apply this to existing templates if you want to edit them.

Comment: I tried my dll is added to the references list but he is not chacked like system so I cant write using "dll name" in the default first lines of when the program is up.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, for that you need to edit the .csproj file of the template you have created and where ever you have added the reference of the DLL, give a hint path to that. Here is the example, I have tried this and it works.

```
<Reference Include="My.Custom.Dll" >
    <HintPath>D:\MyFolder\My.Custom.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

**EDIT:**
and to make sure that the reference automatically added to your new class file you are going to add: Modify this file:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\WebClass\Class.cs` file and add your using statement in that.

**NOTE:** *I am using VS 2017 Professional edition, for you pick your relevant path.*

**Note:** You need to edit `Class.cs` under `WebClass` if you are using `ASP.NET/ASP.NET MVC` project type, for other project types you need to edit the `Class.cs` file from other directories.

I hope now this solves your exact problem also note that Visual Studio updated overwrites these files to keep a watch on that and if that happens don't forget to add that back.

Happy coding...

Comment: It didnt work.. I don't have webclass i have only class folder and I didnt find the csproj file only in a solution that's has been created already

Comment: What type of project template you want? I mean a class library/WebAppl/WinForms?  and what type of item you want to add with using included?

Comment: I want to add simple dll reference when I'm creating simple console application. bcz I have a lot of use function what visual studio doesn't has in its default system dll.